# PowerShell question why did not the script work

Tags: powershell, variables

I would like to find the last scanned pdf in its folder.
After I would like to change its name and move this pdf to an another folder.
The code has already made but it is not working.

```
$lastscan = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scanmap\ | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime, FullName | Sort-Object lastwritetime | Select-Object -Last 1

$01 = Rename-Item $lastscan.FullName -NewName XY.pdf
Move-Item $01 -Destination C:\Users\user016\Desktop
```

Could anyone know what the problem would be with this code?

Thank you!

I have tried to run each command alone and it worked, but together no.
I do not know why.
I hope somebody will be able to help to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Rename-Item does not output anything **unless** you also specify `-PassThru`. In your code, variable $01 therefore stays $null. Also, you can move a file AND change its name using just the Move-Item cmdlet, no need tpo rename it first

Comment: @Theo Thank you, I will try it as soon as I will have free time.

Comment: Please consider posting the solution to your question once it is solved.